# How to get a int from a long double in java?

Tags: java, int, double

I wanna do this math in java:

```
int index = 3 * (9568/20001);
```

in my calculator it shows 3 *( 0.47837608... ) which is 1.43512824..

but, In Java that always give me 0, even I were trying use format, or java.lang.Math.round.

The first postion int **1**  of 1.43512824 is what I want to get.

Comment: With 3 integers you're doing integer math, try `3.0 * (9568/20001);`.

Comment: @Kayaman Would still be `0`, as `9568/20001 == 0`, something like `3 * (9568d/20001d)` would work though

Comment: Err, yeah. Of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int index = (int)3 * (9568.0/20001);
```

Because an integer divided by an integer gives a integer in java thus your answer will not be accurate. If you write `9568.0/20001` it gives a double result and so result is more accurate.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I was editting it .

Comment: After re-reading, I think the OP wants `1`, so, yep

Comment: It is cool! thanks a lot!      this is very quick fix! (int) 3*( (double) 9568/ (double) 20001)

Comment: @HCOOLH you don't need to cast both of them to double,casting any one would do. The other one will automatically be type casted.